# Is there a way to initialize a array of some objects with the same parameter for the constructer function?

Tags: c++

For example,

```
class JJ
{
public:
    JJ(int c)
    {
        a = c;
    }
    int a;
};
```

I can write

```
JJ z[2] = {6,6};
```

But for `JJ z[100]`, I can't write `{6,6,6....,6}`, so what can I do with that?

Comment: Are you using a compiler supporting C++11 or even C++14 ? If so have a look at std::array

Comment: You could use `std::vector<JJ> z(100, 6);` to create 100 elements with value 6.

Comment: @BoPersson Yes, but what if there are more arguments in the constructor? Besides, there is no way no use JJ z[100] to make it without stl?

Comment: You might want to specify what you mean by "array".   It has more than one meaning in C++.  For example, a C-style array, the `std::array` templated container type in the standard library, possibly even usage of other standard containers (like `std::vector`).  Each choice has different advantages, depending on what you are ACTUALLY doing.   Containers are often considered vastly preferable to C-style arrays, even if beginners think otherwise.

Comment: @Peter The information in your last sentence informs me sth I didn't know. I meant C-style arrays. It seems with C-style arrays, it can't be done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `std::vector` doesn't fit your needs with

```
std::vector<JJ> v(100, JJ(6));
```

You may use `std::array`

```
namespace detail
{

    template <std::size_t N, std::size_t...Is, typename T>
    std::array<T, N> make_array(std::index_sequence<Is...>, const T& t)
    {
        return {{(static_cast<void>(Is), t)...}};
    }

}


template <std::size_t N, typename T>
std::array<T, N> make_array(const T& t)
{
    return detail::make_array<N>(std::make_index_sequence<N>{}, t);
}
```

And then

```
std::array<JJ, 100> a = make_array<100>(JJ(6));
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b43aaca4af55c374)

Comment: The usage of namespace `detail` is unnecessary.

Comment: @Peter: It does compile [Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b43aaca4af55c374).